# Referencing a base64 string from another file

Tags: css, html, visual-studio, base64

In my html page I'm using a base64 coded image inside an image tag:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA" />
```

The actual base64 code is a lot longer, and I use it in quite a few html files. Is there a way I can put the above in a css file, or some other file so I can just reference it by name?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a base64 string instead of a binary, you can do something like for css:

```
.picture {
   background:
     url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA...)
     no-repeat
     left center;
   width: 250px;
   height: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

then apply the picture class to a `div` in your html:

```
<div class="picture"></div>
```

See: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

**Update**: Here's a snippet that inserts the image into a table:

```css
.picture {
   background:
     url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAdUlEQVQ4ja1TQQ7AIAjjER7EZ+qb5DX7Ezu4RYaaTNCkF2KlRQqgD4cEjBkYKzBeD2qrhTTc/5JjEaQV8oKM9IPcFRk6K8QiPW+SX4Rk7C5V7HmfzMJObjjxgMcCnRii9xvdi2RbZXKESXeexjkWpYhabYzzDXHli0yOvPvwAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)
     no-repeat
     center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="picture"></div>
    </td>
    <td>Another Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I put the div inside at td, does that matter?

Comment: I think it should work inside a `td`. Note that the `...` represent the rest of your DataURI and should not literally be included. If you're still running into problems and you update your question with a code sample/snippet, I can take a look at it.